# Zabbix: system.cpu.load[<cpu>,<mode>]

Tags: debian, monitoring, zabbix

I installed Zabbix 4.0 and going through Quickstart: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/devel/manual/quickstart/item

I've added `system.cpu.load[<cpu>,<mode>]` (that's the key that is available in Key list under Select button, exact string `system.cpu.load` like on screenshot in the link is not available) as item for an agent on the host, host is enabled, but values are not read and no matter what I enter as parameters for `[<cpu>,<mode>]` or leave the string as is or delete `[<cpu>,<mode>]` and leave `system.cpu.load` only per the Quickstart link, after adding the Info column displays `Invalid first parameter`.

How do I specify parameters for such keys? Do I? How to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are optional and one should never leave the placeholders like `<cpu>` in.
Leaving just `system.cpu.load` should work - if it does not seem to work, one reason could be the configuration cache. Change the item key and let it sit there for some 10 minutes, it should start gathering values.